# Using SSL with Thrift C# client, Java server

Tags: java, c#, ssl, thrift

To create the certificates(pfx for C#, jks for Java) I followed [this](http://myrandomykien.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/steps-to-create-self-signed-certificate.html) guide

C# client:

```
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "pass");
TStreamTransport socket = new TTLSSocket(host, port, cert, (o, c, chain, errors) => true, null);

var transport = new TBufferedTransport(socket);
TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
_client = new HfmConnectorService.Client(protocol);

_client.InputProtocol.Transport.Open();
```

Java Server:

```
TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters params = new TSSLTransportFactory.TSSLTransportParameters();

File keystoreFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\keystore\\hfmcon.jks");
if(!keystoreFile.exists())
    throw new IOException("Keystore file missing"); 

params.setKeyStore(keystoreFile.getPath(), "pass");
TServerSocket serverTransport = TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(port, 10000, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), params);
```

The client times out on this line

```
_client.InputProtocol.Transport.Open();
```

Comment: What is the question? What does timeout mean? Any exception thrown?

Comment: It sounds to be more of a networking issue rather than programming. Could you please share the output of network exchange between server and client?

Comment: did you ever come right using the thrift library and api?

Comment: @Neil oh dear it did work eventually, but I left that job 1 year ago and can't remember what I did to fix :(